# How to open the chrome browser using air native process?

Tags: air, adobe

I always get that ArgumentError: Error #3214: NativeProcessStartupInfo.executable does not specify a valid executable file.

I do not know why. Is there anybody who sees my fault?

Here is my code

```
if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
        {

            var file:File = File.userDirectory;
            file = file.resolvePath("AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");

            var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
            var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();

            var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            args.push("https://www.google.com");

            nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

            process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error basically means, that he can't find the executable file under the given URL.

Have you checked, that your chrome browser is really installed in your user directory (C://User/...) and not in the program files directory?

Comment: Oh ... what a stupid mistake. It works fine with var file:File = new File('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'); ... Thanks for your answer!